# How to return pre-gziped data from an action in mvc core?

Tags: asp.net-core

If i have pre gziped data in my database, how do i return that from a controller when i have dynamic compression enabled? Is there a way to tell iis/mvc core "don't recompress this"?

If i simply return a filedata i assume IIS will rezip it and add the content encoding, is there a safe way to have iis handle compressing everything (static and dynamic) and still tell it "no, just for this action, consider the output to be pre-gzipped"?

```
public IActionResult GetImage(int Id)
    {
        var img = Context.Images
            .Single(i => i.Id == Id);
        return new FileContentResult(img.Data, img.MIME); // What could i do if i wanted, just for this action, to have img.Data already compressed in the database, while everywhere else i have it uncompressed and DO want IIS to compress it?
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could exclude specific MIME types.

```
services.AddResponseCompression(options =>
{
    options.ExcludedMimeTypes = new List<string> { "image/jpeg" };
});
```

For more granular control over compressing or not compressing specific actions...I'm not sure.

Comment: Sadly yes, i do need something at the action level, not at the MIME type level :(